# Кто такие варяги

Tags: этимология

Эти народы называли норманны, викинги, скандинавы. Откуда же взялось русское название "варяги"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ВАРЯГИ** - «выходцы из Скандинавии». Слово известно с IX в. Достоверной этимологии не имеет. Одни считают, что оно заимствовано из др.-исл. яз., где *varingr (vaeringr) образовано от var «обет, присяга» и значило «воин, давший присягу» (как известно, норманны служили в качестве наемных воинов на Руси и в Византии). На слав. почве др.-исл.* varingr преобразовалось в *варягь*. В нем отпал конечный r, сочетание in 
изменилось в носовой е > а, давший соврем. ['а] (графич. Я). 
Другие исследователи полагают, что др.-рус. слово *варягъ* образовано с пом. суф. 
со знач. лица -яг- (< и.-е. *-ing-/-*ang-) от того корня *вар-* < и.-е. *var-/*vor-/*ver-, что в словах* варить *«уберечь, защищать» и* вера*, а также др.-рус.* варъ *«сторожение» (ср. бел.* варта *- «стража», вартаўнік - «стражник»). 
В памятниках XIII в. отмечается слово* варугъ *«варяг». Возможно, это чередов. суф. -яг-/'-уг-. От корня* var- серб. *варошь* «город, острог»; словом, varuh «хранитель, опекун, защитник». Следоват., **варяг** — первонач. «защитник», затем — «чужеземный воин (не только с севера), которому доверяли защиту князя, его семьи и власти» > «наемник» > «скандинав». 
Существовала еще одна версия (Шахматов, Пресняков) происхождения слова **варяги** от названия франков (*фряг* - множ.число - *фрязи*) через посредство аваров. Но Фасмер подчеркивает неправильность этой версии.